# Confusion on how to properly use reducer in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was learning Redux and wanted to properly understand how reducer works. If you look at the reducer called `titleReducer`:

```
const initialState={
titleColor: null,
}

const titleReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case TURN_TITLE_GREEN: 
      return {
        ...state,
        titleColor: 'green'
      }
    case UPDATE_TITLE: 
      return {
        ...state,
        title: action.payload
      }
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

So, I wanted to ask some questions on the above code. Firstly, imagine that there are three reducers: reducer1. reducer2 and titleReducer(I know silly example but bear with me). The question is why even if state of titleReducer has only one property "titleColor", we need to create new make a copy of state by using ...state. What if we just use:

```
{
            title: action.payload
          }
```

The second question is ok every time titleReducer get "TURN_TITLE_GREEN" action, the reducer takes the previous state and creates a new copy and sends back to a component. The question is "where is the previous state is taken from? I mean, is it true that when titleReducer receives the action of TURN_TITLE_GREEN, it creates new copy and at the same time puts 'titleColor: 'green' into state which will serve as previous state next time. Is that true?"

Comment: Your 2nd concern is true and bout the 1st question, yes if you only have one property you can directly retrun that i.e { title: action.payload } but since your state also has title so you can not do that, otherwise when you will update the title, titleColor will be gone.

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb, hi Muhammad, sorry just wanted to clarify about my second question. So,  when reducer takes the previous state and creates a new copy like this: {
        ...state,
        titleColor: 'green'
      }, then only titleColor: 'green' is placed into state(which will be kept in RAM). Right?

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb, so basically the property that we want to overwrite will be the one that is put into state. Right?

Comment: yes only that property gets overwritten by the reducer and all other properties will remain same.